# REST API: Return error for GET request if document would change depending on query parameter?

Tags: rest, error-handling, api-design

We are currently implementing a REST API for handling shopping carts in an online shop. For this we require the ability to change the purchase currency of the cart. Similar APIs in our system use query parameters for changing things like locale or currencies, e. g. for retrieving product information (including prices in a specific currency), you would issue a request like: `GET /products/<product-id>?currency=USD`

For our cart API, changing the currency like that would mean that we would need to trigger a calculation internally with the prices in the new currency; if there are products in the cart which are not available in this currency, then those products would be removed. As GET requests should only retrieve data, but not change it, we don't want to trigger a calculation for the GET request. We are unsure how to handle it though: Should we return the cart in the old currency and simply ignore the fact that the client requested a different currency, or should we return an error that the cart is not valid for the requested currency (and therefore not return the cart document at all)?

When issueing a POST or PUT/PATCH request for the cart with the new currency, it will be recalculated in any case, so there's no problem in that case.

Another approach would be to include the currency as a field in the resource document instead of a query parameter. This would mean it could not be changed via GET requests, though via POST/PUT/PATCH a client could specify the currency explicitly via the request body. However, this solution would be different from other APIs in our system, which is also not optimal.

If you see another solution, feel free to suggest it as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you make it more clear like if the item is of different currency
   your system support for currency conversion or you simply want to
   discard those items.
2. Basically you should go for currency conversion while calculating
   the total price instead of converting while adding to the cart
3. Or you should take currency as path parameter instead of query param and make it fix in the rest uri as per the user currency.So that a user cannot request any item of different currency other than its currency(assuming user has to set his currency)

Comment: 1. We do not use automatic currency conversion, but instead you can specify prices for each currency in the backoffice.  
2. Automatic currency conversion is not used because this may lead to scenarios where prices do not add up to the total because of rounding issues.  
3. We have the business requirement that a user should be able to change the currency anytime (so it's not fixed per se). When changing the currency, the cart should be displayed in the new currency, but we do not know how to handle this for GET requests. It would be OK if the client has to send another (PATCH) request.